# What is the meteor/rock protruding from the Red Dwarf?

Tags: red-dwarf

I've been watching the later seasons of the show, and in some shots of the ship's model it looks like a section has merged with a meteor or some sort of rock.

[image]
<sub><sup>[Red Dwarf: Opening Sequence](https://youtu.be/zV0hwZwNQZc?t=37s)</sup></sub>

**Was Red Dwarf, at some point in its history, struck by an asteroid that lodged in its hull?**

Answer (score 11):

According to the show's model-maker, the asteroid hit the Red Dwarf significantly *before* [everyone died](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shs7VQhVvxA).

> *"Rob and Doug didn't want it to look like a sophisticated spaceship –
> they wanted it to look like something that had been around for
> donkey's years," recalled Wragg of his brief. **"A meteorite had
> embedded itself in it – so they left it there!"***
>
> <sub><sup>[Peter Wragg: Designer best known for the 'Red Dwarf' spaceship](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/obituaries/peter-wragg-designer-best-known-for-the-red-dwarf-spaceship-7897119.html)</sup></sub>

and from the same interview

> *“Rob and Doug had this idea about the ram scoop at the front which
> sucked meteorites, etc. in; [in line with] the fact that it was a
> mining vessel.“ Thus, it’s clear that despite the original concept of
> the embedded asteroid being used for mining, **the final model was built
> with the idea that it had been an accidental strike.***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Red Dwarf FAQ](https://hassleinbooks.blogspot.co.uk/2016/12/the-red-dwarf-faq.html)</sup></sub>

This was also addressed in the Red Dwarf book "[Infinity Welcomes Careful Drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dwarf:_Infinity_Welcomes_Careful_Drivers)".

> *A huge, shadowy carbuncle jutted out a mile or so from the red
> monster's belly - **a small moon, torn out of orbit, had flung itself
> into the ship's solar plexus and was now embedded in the hull,** hanging
> there like a giant stone leech.*

---

Other, lower canon interpretations (mostly from concept art stills and interviews) are discussed in detail [here](https://hassleinbooks.blogspot.co.uk/2016/12/the-red-dwarf-faq.html) including the idea that the asteroid is being mined and that it was intentionally captured.

Comment: I always assumed this was how RD mined larger asteroids, and was the one they were working on when the ... incident occurred. But, it being what it is, a joke about the ship being hit seems more fitting.

Comment: @n_b - As arclite's (alas deleted) answer show, in the later series they'd actually made bays for asteroids to sit in.

Answer (score 3):

*Red Dwarf* is a mining ship owned by the Jupiter Mining Corporation. The asteroid(s) we see attached to the hull of the ship are being mined. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacecraft_in_Red_Dwarf) cites [DVD commentary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacecraft_in_Red_Dwarf#cite_note-15) for this:

> "So in the end, that's why there's two asteroid bays on the new Red Dwarf."
>
> <sub><sup>Mike Tucker, BBC Visual Effects</sup></sub>

Comment: This describes the new Red Dwarf (post-reconstruction by the nanites).